# Is the "Send to Kindle" feature for personal documents/PDFs supported on Windows Phone?

Tags: apps, pdf

I'm trying to send a PDF to read on the Kindle app on my Windows Phone per [this tip](http://www.pcworld.com/article/2044412/convert-a-pdf-for-kindle-viewing-no-software-required.html), but it doesn't show up on the phone.

Checking Kindle settings at the Amazon site it's curious that the "Send-to-Kindle" address shows up for the family Android device (blurred out in the pic below) but for my two phones there's just a dash.

Is this something that isn't supported or enabled on Windows Phone?

[image]

Comment: What is it that does not show up?

Comment: @MikaelDúiBolinder the book/PDF ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Amazon's Kindle Personal Document Service, which includes the Send-to-Kindle functionality, is currently not supported on Windows Phone. It's only available for hardware Kindle devices as well as Android and iOS devices.